# Cover/Landing page text position display

Tags: html, css

I am creating a new website via Squarespace platform. The template is Brine Family 7.0.
https://kazoo-bulldog-snp5.squarespace.com/
Password to access is: 1234

I am trying to change to some text display that I am not able to do with the out of the box feature of Squarespace, but I can access some code sections to do some custom.

On the cover/landing page, I have some text displayed on the top of the page, above the logo that is centered. I want to display it on the bottom of the page, just like that:

https://ibb.co/fN1V5th

Do you have any code suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with your content. (Assuming content is placed in h1 tag)

```
h1{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20%; 
}
```